# Sencha Touch 2 How to get selected itemTpl in a list

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

In Sencha Touch 2. How do I get the selected itemTpl in a list view?

So far I have this code:

```
xtype : 'list',
                        store : myStore,
                        id: 'list',
                        itemTpl : "{num}",
                        flex : 1,
                        listeners : {
                            itemsingletap : function(list, idx, target, record, evt) {
                                var item = getItemTpl(); 
                                var tpl = Ext.getCmp('list').getItemTpl();
                                var me = Ext.getCmp('list').selected.getRange();

                                var records = list.getItemTpl();
                                var recordB = record.getRecord(item);                        
                                var selected = record.get('selected');

                                console.log(selected);

                                view.push({
                                    xtype : 'hView'
                                });
```

Yes, I have tried everything I can think of. ;)

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean you just want the num value from the template?

Comment: Yes, well everything in the itemTpl. I shortened the itemTpl for this question, but in my code it's much longer, I need all of it in a var. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get the generated html from the itemTpl to use in another view?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to get the generated html, but I am going to need it in several places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the target element passed in that event handler, you can then just reference the dom property on the element instance to get the generated html from your itemTpl. It's then up to you how you store that for use elsewhere

Comment: When I console.log(target); to see what's in it I get [object Object]... Ideas?

Comment: Yes it's an Ext.Element instance, so if you break on that console line and inspect the properties of target you will see dom in there